# My JS is not running, shows POST error

Tags: javascript, post

I am writing an online loan calculator for practice. The data processing is all done on the client-side, however, JSFiddle wants me to use `POST`. Why is this? Could this be related to the fact that when the calculate button is clicked locally, the form just clears? The code in a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TJonS/CuzSM/

Also, why isn't this calculating on click of the button? I have tried debugging multiple times, but Chrome is showing no errors.

Javascript:

```
          function calculate(){
        //get the elements
      var amount = document.getElementById("amount");
      var rate = document.getElementById("rate");
      var duration = document.getElementById("duration");
        //get the values of the elements
      var a = parseFloat(amount.value);
      var r = parseFloat(rate.value);
      var d = parseFloat(duration.value);
        //grab the outputable (readable(ha ha:))) variables
      var principal = a;
      var interest = r/100/12;
      var time = d *12;
        //now the calculation variables
      var x = Math.pow(1+interest, payments);
      var monthlypay = (principal*x*interest)/(x-1);
        //if the result is a finite number, then display it. Else we're messed up!
      if (isFinite(monthlypay)) {
        //fill in outputs
            payment.innerHTML = monthlypay.toFixed(2);
            total.innerHTML = (monthlypay * payments).toFixed(2);
            totalinterest.innerHTML = ((monthlypay*payments)-principal).toFixed(2);
        //save the variables

            save(amount.value, rate.value,duration.value, a.value, r.value, d.value, principal.value, total.value, totalinterest.value)
      }
      //else just make the outputs blank as can be.
      else {
        payment.innerHTML = "";
        total.innerHTML = "";
        totalinterest.innerHTML = "";
      }
}
```

Comment: *What* wants you to use post? *edit* oh I see - you need to give that `<button>` a "type=button" attribute.

Comment: What does `save()` do?  What is the error?  In what way does this code not work as expected?  "JSFiddle wants you to use POST"?  What does jsFiddle have to do with your application?

Comment: Where did you define `save`?

Comment: It wouldn't run locally, so I put it up on jsFiddle to ask about it, and it gave me that error. I was wondering if that was the reason that this wasn't calculating.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just put

```
return false;
```

at the bottom of your calculate function, to stop the default onClick behavior(of the button) performing a form post.

also...

is your if statement "if (isFinite(monthlypay)) {" actually getting focus?
this seems to be wiping the values every time.

```
else {
    payment.innerHTML = "";
    total.innerHTML = "";
    totalinterest.innerHTML = "";
  }
```

check your "isFinite(monthlypay)" function is returning true. (most probably never)

Comment: Yeah, and a lot of other stuff. This answer is not even close to complete. I don't think there is a way anyone could write a complete answer to this question.

Comment: i tried this in users js fiddle, which fixed the post issue.
user wants to calculate values without it posting back, as there is no need to post back. yep code doesn't work, but so what, it answers the post question.

Comment: Well, +1 for understanding the question.

Answer (score 0):

Button without post on click:

```
<input type="button" onclick="dosomething();" value="my button text" />
```